# Figure in function not updated on runtime Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a function `E` which has a for loop, in this loop I open an image to draw on using `imshow(im,'Colormap',jet)` then another function `M` is called, in fn `M` there is another loop where a I'm using the `line` matlab function to draw points in on the image `im`. The problem is that if I run fn `M` without being called from fn `E` "which means only one iteration of the `E` function, the figure appears very quickly and in real time. But if I called it from fn `E` the image don't show up until I quit because the loop has large number of iterations, where only a part of the image is drawn. I don't know how can I make the image shows on real-time showing the updates of every iteration? so if anyone could advise. The code of the two functions is very big that's why I couldn't post it.

This is a sample of my code:

```
%function E
function E
for..
M(D)
end

%function M
function M(D)
imshow(D,'Colormap',jet)
for..
for..
line([i],[j],'Marker','p','color','g','linewidth',1,'MarkerSize',7)
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a small amount of time paused in the for loop to give the time for rendering. e.g use pause(.1) in the loop, after calling function `M`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `pause`, use [`drawnow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html), which explicitly flushes the graphics queue. If you like, you can use `drawnow('expose')`, which may be faster, but things like window resizing in fast loops might not work.

Comment: I'm not using pause, and I'm not sure how can I use drawnow? I've updated my question showing a sample of my code, so if you could please advise

Comment: Why can't you use `drawnow`? Put it right after `imshow` or after `line` or both. Or are you simply missing a `hold on` and your plot elements are disappearing (not what your question says, but maybe what you mean). If you're doing an animation in Matlab you should [read this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/animation.html).

Comment: I've tried using drawnow but its taking along time to complete drawing a 480x640 picture. which is very slow

Comment: That's why Matlab doesn't update the screen automatically – it slows things down. There's no way around that. Rather than calling `drawnow` every iteration just call it every 10 or every 100, what ever is appropriate. Also, if you're adding more and more elements to your plot over time, you're effectively dynamically allocating memory which further slows things down. You may need to rework your code.